# Is there a better way to understand this particle?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I've been reading through Winning Ways and was working through some examples of my own related to cooling and particles, and I managed to stump myself. If we let `G = {{6 | 4} | -5}`, `G` gives off two particles as it cools, at temperatures 1 and 5. The particle at temperature 5 is just `*`, but the particle at temperature 1 is

```
{4* | -4} - {4 | -4} = {4* | -4} + {4 | -4}
```

If I haven't made a mistake the canonical form for this game is

```
{{8* | *}, {8* | 0} | {0 | -8}, {* | -8}}
```

At some level this makes it pretty clear what's going on: either player can play to `0` or to `*` "in sente", with a threat of `8*` or `-8`. But I'm having a hard time understanding its relationship to other known infinitesimals, aside from simple results like it being confused with `0` and `*` and less than `^^`. I feel like there should be a way to write it in terms of `tiny-8`'s and `miny-8*`'s or something, or at least some inequalities that would situate it within that hierarchy. But I haven't been able to make much headway there. Does anyone have any insight here?